# Call Method of another class in Flask API

Tags: python-3.x, rest, oop, flask

I am trying to expose a data service as an API for a PHP application. I have written the API logic in a file called APILogic.py. The code in this looks like this

```
class APILogic(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # the initialization is done here
        ...

    def APIfunction(self):
        # the API logic is built here, it uses the class variables and methods
        ...
```

I have created another file for the API purpose. Its called API.py. The code in this file looks like this

```
import APILogic from APILogic
class MyFlask:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = APILogic()

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

my_flask = MyFlask()

@app.route("/Test")
def Test():
    return my_flask.test.APIfunction

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=9999)
```

When I run the code, I get the error

```
> TypeError: APIfunction() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a method.
```

There are no arguments for the APIfunction though.

Please help.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I am already using (). Edited the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a method.

Looks like you're returning the method, but it sounds like you want to return the result of that method:

```
@app.route("/Test")
def Test():
    return my_flask.test.APIfunction()
```

Answer (score -1):

View function should return valid response.
**Sample API code**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: I know this. I was trying to call a method from another call here. I got it to work now. Thanks